# Method that uses Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, methods

OK, so I'm not sure how to explain this, but basically what I want to do is when a web/ URL request is passed in a android phone, I want to find out how to get the Intent of that request/action.

For example, when I do this:

```
MS.FUNCTION("android.content.Intent", new MS.FUNCTION() {
                    public void classLoaded(Class<?> content) {
                        Method **SOMETHING**;
                        try {
                        open = intent.getMethod("open", Integer.TYPE);
                        } catch (NoSuchMethodException d)
```

I want a method (in place of SOMETHING) that passes/uses an Intent when executed, so then I can get extra information. At this point, it is just for web/URL Intents

Thanks so much for any help, and sorry for the probable confusion. I would be glad to answer any other questions regarding clarification.

Also, I have been to the android Intent website, and I have not found what I am looking for. However, this could very easily just be my searching skills.

Comment: this is not clear at all, what are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: I'm really sorry, and the purpose is confusing, but I am basically looking in the phone for a certain method that, when a user opens a webpage on their phone, it passes/uses an Intent to do open the webpage. I specifically am trying to find a method that passes these requirements. Does this help?